# Discretionary page break in an "align" display

Tags: align, page-breaking

> Praesent quis nunc luctus, imperdiet leo in, rutrum nulla. Etiam vitae turpis sed risus rutrum luctus. Phasellus venenatis id erat ut consequat. Curabitur lacinia enim ac ipsum accumsan tempus.

```
\begin{align*}
f_Y(w) = {} & \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)} \int_0^\infty (wv)^{\alpha_1-1} e^{-wv} v^{\alpha_2} e^{-v} \, dv \\[6pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)} \cdot w^{\alpha_1-1} \int_0^\infty v^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2-1} e^{-(w+1)v} \,dv \\[6pt]
= {} &  \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)} \cdot \frac{w^{\alpha_1-1}}{(1+w)^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}} \int_0^\infty ((w+1)v)^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2-1} e^{-(w+1)v} ((w+1)\,dv) \\[6pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)} \cdot \frac{w^{\alpha_1-1}{(1+w)^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}} \int_0^\infty v^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2-1} e^{-v} \,dv \\[6pt]
= {} &  \frac {\Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)}{\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)} \cdot \frac{w^{\alpha_1-1}}{(1+w)^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}}
\end{align*}
```

Since there's not enough room on the page below "accumsan tempus"  for this whole "align" display, LaTeX puts a page break there. But there is enough room for the first two lines of the display. Is there a standard way to get LaTeX to put the page break at whatever place within the display it finds to be necessary?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Aligning equal signs in long equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425472/5764)

Comment: The suggestion is to use `\allowdisplaybreaks` (see the [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/amsmath)).

Comment: @Werner : What if I want LaTeX to insert on the last line something like "continued on the next page$\,\longrightarrow$" at the appropriate spot? Is there a standard way to do that?

Comment: It's better to leave such decisions at the last moment and place `\displaybreak` at the appropriate spot when no other solution is feasible; using `\allowdisplaybreaks` may end up in breaks at undesirable places.

Comment: From the `amsmath` users guide: "When display breaks are enabled with `\allowdisplaybreaks`, the `\\*` command can be used to prohibit a pagebreak after a given line, as usual."